# php - How to insert looped value of checkbox into a single mysql_query

Tags: php

I have here a looped value of checkboxes let's assume I have 3 increments

```
<?php foreach ($times as $time) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b1" value=" <?php echo $time->format('h:i a'), '-', $time->add($interval)->format('h:i a'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

In the `foreach` it display 3 checkboxes that has different value.
Now for example i checked 2 boxes. The query must run twice? Or better yet, the 2 checked value must be inserted to the db.

```
$b = $_POST['b'];
$ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ehr_schedule3(`sched3_time) VALUES('$b')");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Make the browser return an array of `b`'s to PHP like this `name="b[]"`

Comment: Remember only checked checkboxes will get returned from the browser to the PHP script

Comment: I would if I could. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your checkboxes have the same name, so `$_POST['b']` will just get the value of the last one. To get multiple values, you need to use an array-style name:

```
<?php foreach ($times as $time) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="<?php echo $time->format('h:i a'), '-', $time->add($interval)->format('h:i a'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Then `$_POST['b']` will be an array of all the values.

```
foreach ($_POST['b'] as $b) {
    $b = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ehr_schedule3(`sched3_time) VALUES('$b')");
}
```

I also took out `id="b1"` because you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. If you really need the inputs to have IDs (why?), you'll need to give them different ones, perhaps by using the array index as part of the ID.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Im just wondering why use `mysql_real_escape_string` if I have a predefined value for each?

Comment: You can't control what the browser sends, it doesn't have to be one of your predefined values.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a counter to count bs:

```
<?php
$count = 0;//to count the rows if they are dynamic
foreach ($times as $time) {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="b<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $time->format('h:i a'), '-', $time->add($interval)->format('h:i a'); ?>">
<?php 
$count++;
} 
?>
<input name="rowCount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" /><!-- to store number of inputs -->
```

then in your insert function

```
$b_count = $_POST['rowCount'];//to store count of b
$my_quries = [];
for($i=0; $i<$b_count; $++){
    $b = $_POST['b'.$i];//get the corresponded b from POST req
    $my_quries[] = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ehr_schedule3(`sched3_time) VALUES('$b')");
    //you can execute the query in this loop or another one as you like
}
```